# Should I setup a new Google Analytics profile after a site overhaul?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

We are transitioning our in house eCommerce site to Magento. We currently have done a soft roll-out of the Magento site side-by-side with our current site, making it a subdomain using `www1`.

Magento has plenty of gotchas so we wanted to ease traffic into it. Anyway it's been over a month and I setup a Google Analytics profile for the new site so we could do some analysis on it. Now we are thinking about making it fully live and giving it the `www` subdomain instead of `www1`.

My question is if it's okay to abandon the `www1` Google Analytics profile and replace it with the `www` profile once the cut-over is complete?

Also, if I stayed with the `www1` profile am I just losing the ability to compare past data on the same screen? Seems I will always have the history of the `www` profile, I just won't be able to overlay it with the data from the new profile.

Part of me likes the idea of the new profile because I did a better job of setting that up than the `www` profile, which was setup years ago and not quite as good as it could have been.

Comment: If you have a boss or client, preserve the data even if it is on paper in the end. So for a period, it may be a good idea to measure both versions of the site and then eventually make a hard copy and remove the extra GA profile. CYA is always a good idea. If you are not concerned about CYA, then it may be good to measure differences in performance and may give you ideas which way to go for the future.

Comment: I plan on keeping both profiles, I would just make one of them inactive. So either way I will have the history  of the other. I'm wondering if being able to overlay historical data over current data is the only major feature I'm losing by not switching the new site to use the current profile for tracking.

Comment: Gotcha! I have no idea. Sorry. I am not into GA as much as others are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the new profile, you will not be able to see all the history on a single graph.

I would recommend using the old profile and updating its setup with what is better from your ww1 profile.   I don't know of any settings in Google Analytics that can't be applied to an existing profile.

Comment: If that is the only major feature I'll be losing I might just go ahead with the new profile. Can you think of anything else significant that I wouldn't be able to do? I should add that most of our historical comparisons are done outside of GA.

Comment: Nothing that I can think of.